# veusz does not start (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: package-management

Clicking Veusz icon does nothing- Trying to star from terminal (command = `veusz`) produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/veusz", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('veusz==3.3.1', 'gui_scripts', 'veusz')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/veusz/veusz_main.py", line 369, in run
    app.startup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/veusz/veusz_main.py", line 267, in startup
    self.splash = makeSplash(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/veusz/veusz_main.py", line 69, in makeSplash
    font.setPointSize(font.pointSize()*1.5)
TypeError: setPointSize(self, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Comment: looks like a bug in Veusz, you can report an issue on their [github](https://github.com/veusz/veusz/issues)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug in veusz](https://github.com/veusz/veusz/issues/563) that only occurs when using Python 3.10. It has been fixed as of veusz v3.4 (you're using 3.3.1). Upgrade to the newest version and the issue should be gone. If it isn't, you can report that the issue still exists at the link above.